# How does Webpack require.ensure determine dependencies to load?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I've been debugging an issue with too many chunks being loaded, and I've identified that the initiator for the loading of many of my chunks is a `require.ensure` call.

To simplify the problem, I started commenting out code to see how that affected chunk loading.  To my surprise, even when I had commented out all of my code except for some plumbing, I still see the `require.ensure` loading many chunks.

In its most extreme simplified version, here is the entire contents of the module containing the `require.ensure`.  This is literally everything:

```
export function myFunction(options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function success(data, status, xhr) {
            require.ensure([], function() {
                // body removed...
            }, "my-chunk");
        }
        success(null, null, null);
    });
}
```

When webpack processes this `require.ensure`, it generates a `Promise.all` that contains `__webpack_require__.e` calls for **80 chunks**.  This is what the "webpack internal" version of the above module looks like (with many of the requires removed for brevity):

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", ({
    value: true
}));
exports.myFunction = myFunction;

function myFunction(options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        function success(data, status, xhr) {
            Promise.all( /* require.ensure | my-chunk */ [
                __webpack_require__.e("chunk1"), 
                __webpack_require__.e("chunk2"),

                ... 77 more __webpack_require__.e calls

                __webpack_require__.e("my-chunk")]).then((function() { 
                    
                    // body removed...
            }).bind(null, __webpack_require__)).catch(__webpack_require__.oe);
        }

        success(null, null, null);
    });
}
```

My question is where could these dependencies be coming from if the module containing the `require.ensure` has no explicit dependencies itself?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I misunderstood the purpose of the `chunkName` argument of `require.ensure`.  I had thought that the dependencies needed by the callback would be added to the chunk group specified by `chunkName`, but that only those needed dependencies would actually be loaded by this particular `require.ensure` at runtime.

In fact, it does two things.  It does add the callback dependencies into the chunk group, but it also loads *all* chunks from that chunk group at runtime, regardless of how those chunks ended up in that chunk group.

So, in my example above, by specifying `my-chunk` in my empty `require.ensure` I am still causing all chunks that are part of the `my-chunk` group from other parts of the code to be loaded.  That is where the 80 chunks were coming from.